# Google Sheets White Background is not White

Tags: google-sheets

When I try to print a Google sheets document, it takes way too long to print. Printing from excel or anything else does not have this problem. Hopefully I can explain correctly.

I'm seeing that the default shade of white background in Google sheets is not clear. When I print any Google sheet, even a newly created blank sheet, the border of the printed page has no ink but the rest of the sheet is ever so slightly shaded a darker shade of white. I think this is why it's taking so long to print. The printer is trying to print this other shade of white background instead of just not printing anything since the paper is already white.

I'm using the default Google sheets background color. How can I stop the printer from printing this different shade of white that is taking forever?

Comment: Every sheet, even a new sheet with nothing in it

Comment: Try turning off gridlines